# how to redraw or invalidate ubuntu desktop programmatically by c or python

Tags: windows, nautilus, gui, gtk3, xdotool

I am now using ubuntu16.04 with GNOME desktop environment. I can change attributes(eg `metadata::nautilus-icon-position`) of files on desktop by c or python, but desktop display does not update. Then i simulate a "F5" press event using `xdo_send_keysequence_window(x, CURRENTWINDOW, "F5", 0)` from `libxdo`, display now update but with a blink (It seems to me that all widgets on desktop are first cleared, then redrawed). If i continuously change file attributes and simulate "F5" press, desktop keeps updating and blinking.

I have two questions:

1. how does desktop system handle "F5" press event? (first clear all widget except background on desktop and then maybe in next time slice redraw all widgets??)
2. is there a way(api interface or send events to desktop) to invalidate or redraw desktop without blinking,just like a normal GUI application(widget.move() or container.invalidate())?

I have searched a lot and can not find answer.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As `F5` is the keybinding for the *Refresh* function, it is handled as such. This is no different than hitting `F5` in a web browser to refresh. The page is cleared, and a new request is made to the server. In the case of Nautilus, this means the view is cleared and the directory re-scanned.

You could possibly write a plug-in (extension) for Nautilus, which could grab the actual widget for the background and then invalidate only a partial rectangle, though I'm not sure this would solve your problem (you should be able to test by moving windows over the area in question and then moving them away again).

The best solution here though, would be to file a bug against Nautilus, and solve the problem directly, so that when such attributes are altered on files, Nautilus will do the correct thing and change the icon position or such.